# Use re.sub to replace replace variable that is regex with a string

Tags: python

I need to replace KEY from with VAL. Key is a regex like import.* and val is a string like "important".
I know that this code is not good, because key is regex, but i couldn't find a solution that works.

```
#import stem dict
d = {}
with open("Stem rečnik.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       key, val = line.split(":")
       d[key.replace("\n","")] = val.replace("\n","")

#define tokenizer
def custom_tokenizer(text):
    #split- space
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
    #stemmer
    for key,val in d.items():
        tokens=[token.replace(key,val) for token in tokens]
    #remove special characters
    tokens=[re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]',"",token) for token in tokens]
    return tokens  
cv=CountVectorizer(tokenizer= custom_tokenizer,analyzer ='word',encoding='utf-8', min_df=0, max_df=1.0)
post_textCV= cv.fit_transform(post_text)
df=DataFrame(post_textCV.A, columns=cv.get_feature_names())
print(df.head)
```

So, the problem is this line here:

```
tokens=[token.replace(key,val) for token in tokens]
```

Comment: I don't really agree with the duplicate target. It sounds irrelevant. And it's really a bad original question with below par 0-score accepted answer. I don't even understand the answer...

Comment: There is nothing about re.sub replacement. This is really not helping me out.

Comment: @Alexander reopened the question (someone already voted for it). I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Alexander that said I understand perfectly the urge to close a question as a duplicate to avoid dump copied/pasted answers... I'm so frustrated when someone answers _before_ I find the exact dupe.

Comment: @hope94 Would you mind posting a small sample of the data?  Presumably from "Stem rečnik.txt" and `post_text`.

Answer (score 1):

`token.replace(key,val)` invokes `str.replace` which is basic string replace.

To call regex replace just do this instead:

```
tokens=[re.sub(key,val,token) for token in tokens]
```

that said, this seems rather ineffective, rebuilding a list comprehension for each key/val couple.

Comment: Code executes more than 6 minutes, and is still not over, it happens to me everytime when something is not ok. The rest of the code works fine when i don't run this part.

Comment: that's what I thought. I edited my answer to show a really efficient solution. More complex, but faster.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement it, it will take some time for me to study it, because Í've never used before things you mentioned here.I am new in Python. So i tried just to copy those two lines, but i got an error: KeyError: 'intesa'. (intesa is a value in the dictionary)

Comment: damn, my solution doesn't work when there are patterns... it works fine when keys are actual values (so the matched group IS the key, but not here)

Comment: i tried this, but it takes too long. I suppose because there is a lot of iterations...

tokens=[re.sub(r'%s' %key, '%s'%val,token ) for token in tokens]

Comment: yes, I wouldn't use a list comprehension here. Just perform the x substitution on each token, and append it to a new token list. Should be faster (even if not optimal). Want me to suggest something?